# Join with null value enable in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am running a Linq Query and I am expecting null for ParentName = functionNavigation_b.Title where ParentID = functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID has 0 value and I want to add in list but apparently my join is voiding that. I need to add that.

```
from functionNavigation in Sys_Nav_Functions
 join functionHierarchy in Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchies on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionHierarchy.Function_ID
 join functionNavigation_b in Sys_Nav_Functions on functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID equals functionNavigation_b.Function_ID  
 join functionInController in Sys_Nav_FunctionInControllers on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionInController.Function_ID
 join functionController in Sys_Nav_FunctionControllers on functionInController.ControllerID equals functionController.ControllerID
 join functionInAction in Sys_Nav_FunctionInActions on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionInAction.Function_ID
 join functionAction in Sys_Nav_FunctionActions on functionInAction.ActionID equals functionAction.ActionID
    select new {
        functionNavigation.Function_ID, 
        functionNavigation.Title, 
        functionNavigation.Hierarchy_Level, 
        ParentID = functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID, 
        ParentName = functionNavigation_b.Title,
        functionController.ControllerID, 
        functionController.ControllerName, 
        functionAction.ActionID, 
        functionAction.ActionName }
```

Comment: You should use LEFT JOIN then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 from functionNavigation in Sys_Nav_Functions
 join functionHierarchy in Sys_Nav_FunctionHierarchies on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionHierarchy.Function_ID
 join functionNavigation_b in Sys_Nav_Functions on functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID equals functionNavigation_b.Function_ID  
        into tmp from functionNavigation_b in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
 join functionInController in Sys_Nav_FunctionInControllers on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionInController.Function_ID
 join functionController in Sys_Nav_FunctionControllers on functionInController.ControllerID equals functionController.ControllerID
 join functionInAction in Sys_Nav_FunctionInActions on functionNavigation.Function_ID equals functionInAction.Function_ID
 join functionAction in Sys_Nav_FunctionActions on functionInAction.ActionID equals functionAction.ActionID
    select new {
        functionNavigation.Function_ID, 
        functionNavigation.Title, 
        functionNavigation.Hierarchy_Level, 
        ParentID = functionHierarchy.Parent_Function_ID, 
        ParentName = (functionNavigation_b != null) : functionNavigation_b.Title ? "", // 
        functionController.ControllerID, 
        functionController.ControllerName, 
        functionAction.ActionID, 
        functionAction.ActionName }
```

Comment: If in .Net 4.6.1 A bit of a cleaner way will be: ParentName = functionNavigation_b ?.Title.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Left Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) to get the records